# Multiple conditions on IF with Shell Script

Tags: shell, sh

A coworker of mine made this check for a file processing script which extracts data from our database and put it on some .txt files.

```
if [ $File_ID < 4 ] || [ $File_ID > 64 ] || [ $File_ID -eq 60 ] && [ $File_ID != 0 ] && [ $File_ID != 1 ]; then
```

**Rules:**

1. If File_ID = 0, it extracts all files.
2. For 2 and 3 it should fail.
3. Between 4 and 64 it should pass, with the exception being 60.

Right now, I'm trying to generate the file with File_ID equal to 11, but I'm getting false. What's wrong in this statement?

Comment: Your coworker should have used [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). It would warn that e.g. `[ $File_ID < 4 ]` is not a valid comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `case` statement instead along with an `if` statement:

```
if [ "$File_ID" -lt 0 ] || [ "$File_ID" -gt 64 ]; then
  printf 'File_ID %d out of range\n' "$File_ID"
  exit 1;
fi

case $File_ID in
   0) extract-files ;;
   1) printf "You didn't say what to do with 1\n" >&2; exit 1 ;;
   2|3|60) printf 'Error\n' >&2; exit 1 ;;
   *) printf 'Pass\n' ;;
esac
```